# Correlation between opening usage

Tags: opening, statistics

Is there statistical analysis of which openings players play as Black when they play a certain opening as White and vice versa?

For example, is it the case that people that play 1. ..c6, often leading to a more positional game, play 1.d4 / 1.Nf3 /1.c4 more likely as White than players that answer 1. ..e5?

Is there analysis available correlating openings for Black and White?

Comment: Interesting.  If I play the Kings Indian Attack do I play the Kings Indian as well?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can use your database (or the [lichess analysis board](https://lichess.org/analysis)) to see the most popular replies to certain openings.

Lichess specifically sorts between masters and their online database, and you can see the exact number of times (and the correlating percentage out of the most popular replies) moves have been played in response.

Comment: Poster is asking about correlation of openings played by white to openings played by black by the same player.

Comment: If they use lichess, you can view this by a specific user. Same with other databases like professionals via ChessBase.

Comment: Poster is asking if there is any analysis available, not how such analysis might be done.

Comment: What I would need is something like that lichess opening explorer, just that I can filter for (all) players who predominantly play a specific opening. I know I can filter for individual players, but no group of players.